# creating pivot tables in excel via openxml

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk, control-m

i need to make manipulation on excel file and create few complex pivot tables(using filters) using openxml.
additionaly if someone know if its posible to use the BMC control-m on the batch application?

i tried implementing in sheet2 the pivot table but it keeps staying empty without pivot table

```
          PivotTableDefinition abc = GeneratePivotTablePart1();
            SheetData xlPivotSheetData = new SheetData(abc);
            
            WorksheetPart worksheetPart2 = workbookpart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
            Worksheet worksheet2 = new Worksheet();

            worksheet2.AppendChild(xlPivotSheetData);
            worksheetPart2.Worksheet = worksheet2;

            //package.WorkbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild(new Sheets()
            //package.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>().AppendChild(new Sheet()                    //= abc;
            Sheet sheet2 = new Sheet()
            {
                Id = app.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart2),//package.WorkbookPart.WorksheetParts.First()),

                SheetId = 2,

                Name = "PivotTable"

            };
            sheets.Append(sheet2);
```

this part is the function creating the pivot table

```
   private static PivotTableDefinition GeneratePivotTablePart1()
    {
        var element =
            new PivotTableDefinition(
                new Location()
                {
                    Reference = "DataSource!A1:D5",
                    FirstHeaderRow = (UInt32Value)1U,
                    FirstDataRow = (UInt32Value)2U,
                    FirstDataColumn = (UInt32Value)1U
                },
                new PivotFields(
                    new PivotField(
                        new Items(
                            new Item() { Index = (UInt32Value)0U },
                            new Item() { Index = (UInt32Value)1U },
                            new Item() { ItemType = ItemValues.Default }
                        )
                        { Count = (UInt32Value)3U }
                    )
                    {
                        Axis = PivotTableAxisValues.AxisRow,
                        ShowAll = false
                    },
                    new PivotField()
                    {
                        DataField = true,
                        ShowAll = false
                    },
                    new PivotField(
                        new Items(
                            new Item() { Index = (UInt32Value)0U },
                            new Item() { Index = (UInt32Value)1U },
                            new Item() { ItemType = ItemValues.Default }
                        )
                        { Count = (UInt32Value)3U }
                    )
                    {
                        Axis = PivotTableAxisValues.AxisColumn,
                        ShowAll = false
                    },
                    new PivotField() { ShowAll = false },
                    new PivotField() { ShowAll = false }
                )
                { Count = (UInt32Value)5U },
                new RowFields(
                    new Field() { Index = 0 }
                )
                { Count = (UInt32Value)1U },
                new RowItems(
                    new RowItem(
                        new MemberPropertyIndex()),
                    new RowItem(
                        new MemberPropertyIndex() { Val = 1 }),
                    new RowItem(
                        new MemberPropertyIndex()
                    )
                    { ItemType = ItemValues.Grand }
                )
                { Count = (UInt32Value)3U },
                new ColumnFields(
                    new Field() { Index = 2 }
                )
                { Count = (UInt32Value)1U },
                new ColumnItems(
                    new RowItem(
                        new MemberPropertyIndex()),
                    new RowItem(
                        new MemberPropertyIndex() { Val = 1 }),
                    new RowItem(
                        new MemberPropertyIndex()
                    )
                    { ItemType = ItemValues.Grand }
                )
                { Count = (UInt32Value)3U },
                new DataFields(
                    new DataField()
                    {
                        Name = "Sales by Country and Period",
                        Field = (UInt32Value)1U,
                        BaseField = 0,
                        BaseItem = (UInt32Value)0U,
                        NumberFormatId = (UInt32Value)44U
                    }
                )
                { Count = (UInt32Value)1U },
                new Formats(
                    new Format(
                        new PivotArea()
                        {
                            Outline = false,
                            CollapsedLevelsAreSubtotals = true,
                            FieldPosition = (UInt32Value)0U
                        }
                    )
                    { FormatId = (UInt32Value)1U }
                )
                { Count = (UInt32Value)1U },
                new PivotTableStyle()
                {
                    Name = "PivotStyleLight16",
                    ShowRowHeaders = true,
                    ShowColumnHeaders = true,
                    ShowRowStripes = false,
                    ShowColumnStripes = false,
                    ShowLastColumn = true
                }
            )
            {
                Name = "PivotTable11",
                CacheId = (UInt32Value)57U,
                ApplyNumberFormats = false,
                ApplyBorderFormats = false,
                ApplyFontFormats = false,
                ApplyPatternFormats = false,
                ApplyAlignmentFormats = false,
                ApplyWidthHeightFormats = true,
                DataCaption = "Values",
                UpdatedVersion = 3,
                MinRefreshableVersion = 3,
                ShowCalculatedMembers = false,
                UseAutoFormatting = true,
                ItemPrintTitles = true,
                CreatedVersion = 3,
                Indent = (UInt32Value)0U,
                Outline = true,
                OutlineData = true,
                MultipleFieldFilters = false,
                RowHeaderCaption = "Countries",
                ColumnHeaderCaption = "Periods",
                FieldListSortAscending = true
            };

        return element;
    }
```

Comment: I usually create pivot tables using only c# code.  I do queries of the data and then group the results just like an excel pivot.

Comment: Do you use openxml? my main issue is that i cannot use introp.excel component becaouse it doesnt work with bmc, so i'm trying to check if openxml can do the job instead

Comment: Use oledb if you just need data and not formatting.  See : https://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/  The JET driver is windows and works with xls file.  For new files use ACE which comes with Microsoft Office.  If you do not have office than you can download a runtime version of ACE.

Comment: I need data and conditional formating but i need to take the data and create pivot tables and build formulas, is it posible when bmc is running and no office installed?

Comment: You can always add coloring in c#.  Excel is not meant for multi-user environment.  You can have two connection to the database at one time in shared mode, but there is no locking.  So if BMC is making changes to the database at same time oledb than you may get some inconsistencies in the results.

Comment: following the question, how can i add the PivotTableDefinition into the spreadsheet

Comment: I added some code for review, i tried making the pivot table and append it to the spreadsheet but it keeps getting empty spreadsheet

Comment: the BMC is running the ssis that is activating the script of the excel. using excel interop is not working becaouse its an interactive user while the BMC is a server side process. this is why i turn to openxml but not sure it will work properly as well